# JTCalendar creating shadow on left menu controller

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7, calendar, xcode6

I am creating an application which completely depends upon side menu. To create side menu I am using MFSideMenu class. On the landing page I am creating a custom calendar using JTCalendar class.

[image]

Till the time I am not clicking on the calendar and and the landing page left side menu option, there are no issues but after clicking on these options I am getting below image

[image]

Can someone enlighten the issue why this is happening????

Comment: Looks like you have a calendar drawing in the wrong view somehow.  Any chance you could have misdirected the calenders output? Your first screen shot is also showing artifacts of leftover text?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps clicking on the calendar and and the landing page left side menu options might be calling JTCalendar class.So another calendar might have been drawn overlapping the original.

Comment: Yes you are right. I am loading JTCalendar in viewDidLoad method. So whenever this view is loaded, new object of calendar will be created. How could I stop this?

Comment: When do you actually need to draw the Calendar ?

Comment: -->If you don't want to display the calendar as soon as the Left Menu appears,it might be good to remove the code to display calendar from viewDidLoad method.
-->If calendar is to be displayed on an event like, a button click,then draw the calendar in the Action method of that button.
Also,could you please show contents of your viewDidLoad method ?

Comment: After login this is my landing page where in default user will be able to view calendar. Can't move it anywhere.

Comment: - (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
     self.calendar = [JTCalendar new];
    // Or you will have to call reloadAppearance
    {
        self.calendar.calendarAppearance.calendar.firstWeekday = 2; // Sunday == 1, Saturday == 7
        self.calendar.calendarAppearance.dayCircleRatio = 9. / 10.;
        self.calendar.calendarAppearance.ratioContentMenu = 1.;
    }
    
    [self.calendar setMenuMonthsView:self.calendarMenuView];
    [self.calendar setContentView:self.calendarContentView];
    
    [self configureFloatingButton];
    [self.calendar setDataSource:self];
}

Comment: Try commenting 
[self.calendar setMenuMonthsView:self.calendarMenuView];
  &  
 [self.calendar setContentView:self.calendarContentView];

Comment: Unable to view calendar after commenting thess lines.

Comment: Could you zip me the project to alenalexander77@gmail.com

Comment: Sorry can't do that. :-(

Answer (score 0):

Make your **MFSideMenu** untransferable....
Set **Alpha** or **opaque** and hide super view when you are going to show your Side Menu. hope this will help.

Because without sample of your code, we cant say what actually going wrong in your process....